# how to find last empty row, seems some problems in my macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a table from one worksheet to another worksheet and every time it  should perform the action at the first unused row i.e after the end of last copied ranged (Back to back) for that I am using below formula

```
nextrow = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(a & Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

However this one not working properly. I mean it just overwriting at the the last one used "nextrow".

Below is the complete code for your reference. I would highly appreciate your help in this regard.

```
nextrow = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(a & Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("Pay slip").Range("table1").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("sheet2").Cells(nextrow, 1)

Sheets("Pay slip").Range("table2").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("sheet2").Cells(nextrow + 1, 1)

Sheets("Pay slip").Range("table3").CurrentRegion.Copy Sheets("sheet2").Cells(nextrow + 1, 1)
```

Comment: not sure what `a &` doing in code.. and your second and third rows both have `.Cells(nextrow + 1, 1)`, so third line would rewrite result of second line

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Sh as worksheet, Sh2 as worksheet
set Sh = Sheets("sheet2")
set Sh2= Sheets("Pay slip"
with Sh
    nextrow = .Cells( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'next available row on column "A"

    Sh2.Range("table1").Copy .Cells(nextrow, 1) 'if "table1" is a named range, i don't see why you need a .currentregion
    nextrow = .Cells( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'you have to recalculate the new 'nextrow'

    Sh2.Range("table2").Copy .Cells(nextrow, 1) 'i removed the "+1", its already in nextrow formula
    nextrow = .Cells( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'and again, recalculate nextrow

    Sh2.Range("table3").Copy .Cells(nextrow , 1)
end with
```